# NavigationLink will not enable

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a situation where I need to have something selectable from a list. However the thing needs to be an optional. The user is not required to pick one but they might, or might not. If they do pick one they might clear it later.

Based on my somewhat limited SwiftUI knowledge I'm hoping the sample code below is as simple as can be to show the problem I'm running into.

```
struct Thing: Hashable {
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedThing: Thing?
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink(value: selectedThing) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Selected Thing:")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(selectedThing?.name ?? "no thing selected")")
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Thing.self) { _ in
                    Things(selectedThing: $selectedThing)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

// this is the detail view, there will be a list of Things here eventually
struct Things: View {
    @Binding var selectedThing: Thing?
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello thing: \(selectedThing?.name ?? "")")
    }
}
```

But when ContentView renders the row with the chevron is disabled.

[image]

How do I get this row to be enabled? Can I accomplish this in SwiftUI with an optional like that? If so, what am I missing?

ps. I googled "swiftui navigationlink disabled" and I couldn't find anything for this particular case. There were some with "be sure to use NavigationStack instead of NavigationView"

Using Xcode 15.2.

Comment: Just use `.disabled(_ disabled: )`?  I don't know if you can use `NavigationLink` with `Form`, though.

Comment: @ElTomato I added `.disabled(false)` and it has no effect. And I have lots of other `NavigationLinks` working in a `Form`, just not one with an optional.

Comment: You have your logic back to front. You select from a List, **then**
 you display the details. You are trying to do the opposite.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I understand what you're saying but it's not backwards. `selectedThing` is selected from a list of `Thing`s. Tapping on that row in the screenshot would (if it wasn't disabled) take you to the list of Things where the user could select one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should put the `NavigationStack` outside of the `Form`.

Secondly, you are calling [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(value:label:)-4jswo) of `NavigationLink`. The `value:` parameter takes a `P?`, so here `P` is `Thing`, not `Thing?`. As the documentation says, when `value` is nil, the navigation link is disabled.

What you probably intended to do, is for `P` to be `Thing?`, and `.navigationDestination(for: Thing?.self)` instead of `.navigationDestination(for: Thing.self)`.

You can wrap `selectedThing` in an additional layer of `Optional`. This ensures `value` is never nil (but the value wrapped in it can be).

```
NavigationStack {
    Form {
        NavigationLink(value: Optional.some(selectedThing)) {
            HStack {
                Text("Selected Thing:")
                Spacer()
                Text("\(selectedThing?.name ?? "no thing selected")")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Thing?.self) { _ in
            Things(selectedThing: $selectedThing)
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: you might be reinventing the `.navigationLink` picker style. Consider using a `Picker`:

```
Picker("Selected Thing:", selection: $selectedThing) {
    Text("None").tag(nil as Thing?)
    Text("One").tag(Thing(name: "One") as Thing?)
    Text("Two").tag(Thing(name: "Two") as Thing?)
}
.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
```

Notice that we also wrap the `tag`s in an additional layer of `Optional`.

Comment: Thank you for saying "read the docs" in such a nice way!!  =:-)   The view for selecting the Thing allows the user to select a thing but also create new Things and delete Things so I think the Picker might not work for that.